# Android Webview not loading url if the href starts with "www"

Tags: android, webview

I am loading `webview` from a string fetched from an api call. But if the `href` for the hyperlink starts with "www", then clicking on that link makes the `webview` blank. If `href` starts with "http://www" then the url is getting loaded. Is there any way to make the hyperlink work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the url in your code, like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                if(!url.startsWith("http://"))
                {
                    url = "http://" + url;
                }
                webView.loadUrl(url); 
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```